# Pointer C Language

Tags: c, pointers

i took this example from the deitel's book. Can you please explain how the string1 stores the whole strings?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 80

void mystery1(char *s1, const char *s2); // prototype

int main(void)
{
   char string1[SIZE]; // create char array
   char string2[SIZE]; // create char array

   puts("Enter two strings: ");
   scanf("%79s%79s" , string1, string2);
   mystery1(string1, string2);
   printf("%s", string2);
} 

// What does this function do?
void mystery1(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
   while (*s1 != '\0') {
      ++s1;
   } 

   for (; *s1 = *s2; ++s1, ++s2) {
      ; // empty statement
   } 
}
```

Comment: The `*s1 = *s2` is concatenating the second string on the first, *and* testing for the `'\0'` nul terminator as the loop condition. But it is a recipe for buffer overflow.

Comment: it is strcat. But the limits are wrong, string1 should have 159 bytes

Comment: Actually, [this](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strcat.c.html) is strcat.

Comment: The *mystery* is why the program prints `string2` not `string1`. Is this intended to demonstrate undefined behaviour?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No, actually [this](https://www.deviantart.com/tela-ferrum/art/strcat-277462729) is strcat!

Comment: @WeatherVane: Maybe OP mistyped?

Comment: yes it is mistyped

Comment: but i still couldn't understand how come this two get concatenated cause i percept that there is no special codes for this aim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does this function do?

It concatenates two strings, i.e. it's doing the same as the standard `strcat` function. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html

Assume the input is "Hello World".

Just when the function is called, some where in memory it looks like:

```
String1: Hello\0
         ^
         |
         s1

String2: World\0
         ^
         |
         s2
```

Now this part

```
while (*s1 != '\0') {
  ++s1;
}
```

Moves the pointer `s1` to the end of `String1`. So you have

```
String1: Hello\0
               ^
               |
               s1

String2: World\0
         ^
         |
         s2
```

Then this part

```
for (; *s1 = *s2; ++s1, ++s2) {
  ; // empty statement
}
```

copies characters from `String2` (using `s2`) to the end of `String1` (using `s1`).

After one loop, you'll have:

```
String1: HelloWorldW
                    ^
                    |
                    s1

String2: World\0
          ^
          |
          s2
```

After one more loop, you'll have:

```
String1: HelloWorldWo
                     ^
                     |
                     s1

String2: World\0
           ^
           |
           s2
```

and so on.

In the end you'll have

```
String1: HelloWorld\0
                     ^
                     |
                     s1

String2: World\0
                ^
                |
                s2
```

Net result: `String2` was concatenated to `String1`

A few more words about `for (; *s1 = *s2; ++s1, ++s2) {`

```
The ; says: no initialization needed

The *s1 = *s2; says: Copy the char that s2 points to to the memory that s1 points to. 
Further, it serves as "end-of-loop" condition, i.e. the loop will end when a \0 has 
been copied

The ++s1, ++s2 says: Increment both pointers
```

In this way characters from `String2` are one-by-one copied to the end of `String1`

BTW: Notice that the `main` function is unsafe as too little memory is reserved for `String1`